# SQLite: Average grouped by hour

Tags: sqlite

I have a dataset with Power measurements over several days. I want to find the average value grouped by hour, which sounds pretty straightforward, but I only get one result. I have tried the following (and several variations of this), and I am not sure what I'm missing. I'm using SQLite.

```
select AVG(Power) 
from TrafoTotal
group by strftime('%H', Time);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `strftime()` returns `null` because the column `Time` contains datetime values that are not in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` which is the only valid datetime format for SQLite.
If this is the case then all your datetimes are considered as only 1 group and you get only 1 (wrong) average as result.

So change the format of your dates and your query will work.